# Import User ID with Drupal Feeds

Tags: feeds

Is it somehow possible to import the user ID with feeds. The GUID field is not the ID field, as I just found out, but I need my user IDs with my imported users to stay the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think feeds supports that out of the box, but [there's a patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1570544) for it that is reported to work.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is definitely something, feeds should include into their core.